# Are there appropriate and commonly used properties to express maximum and minimum numeric values in RDF?

Tags: rdf

I'm wondering if there are any RDF properties to be used to express maximum and minimum numeric values for a subject resource.
For example, a resource denotes a result of an experiment that has numeric property value of "1.6e-9 - 2.4e-9".
Could you tell me how to RDFize this statement as simply as possible?

Comment: are you asking for a vocabulary or how to model it in RDF? Also, how will you make use of those min/max value? For validation? For inference? Or just for documentation purposes?

Comment: I'm asking for a vocabulary, and it is used for users to retrieve some relevant data using SPARQL. Therefore the purpose is rather documentation.

Comment: I see, a pragmatic way cold be to just use the XSD vocabulary, e.g. `xsd:minInclusive` and the like

Comment: Thanks. I think `xsd:minInclusive` is a literal data type, and not a predicate. So it is not simple to express that the value types are `xsd:double` and `xsd:minInclusive`, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[schema.org](https://schema.org/QuantitativeValue) has a solid arsenal of usable properties to describe quantities, including `minValue` and `maxValue`:

```
@prefix schema: <http://schema.org> .

<subj> :hasProperty [
  schema:minValue 1.6e-9;
  schema:maxValue 2.4e-9
] .
```